# How to prevent secondary display space from merging with laptop space in macOS?

Tags: macos, mac, desktop, external-display

Any way to maintain space integrity when plugging / unplugging secondary display in macOS?

For example, I like having 4 desktops/spaces (a, b, c, d) on my laptop and 2 on my 2nd monitor (e, f).  When I unplug, space 'f' appends to laptop, such that I have a, b, c, d, f.  Space 'e' merges into 'a', such that 'a' now contains all windows from both 'a' and 'e'.  'e' no longer exists while unplugged.

When I plug back in, 2nd monitor regains both 'e' and 'f' spaces.  the spaces un-merge, and all original 'e' windows (temporarily held in 'a') appear back in 'e' correctly.

Preferred behavior would be to maintain 'e' space, such that unplugging 2nd monitor gives me a, b, c, d, e, f.

Comment: I highly doubt it without a third-party solution.

Comment: I've answered a similar question here: https://superuser.com/a/1221401/454133

Answer (score 0):

I highly doubt it without a third-party solution. I was able to do similar configurations using Matrox Dual-Head To Go, which consisted of hardware and software. That's ancient technology, so I wouldn't recommend that specific solution, but Apple just doesn't offer that kind of customization natively.

Making matters worse, ever since the release of SIP within El Cap, Apple "broke" all the great utility apps, like QuickResSwitcher and TotalSpaces2, unless you're willing to run your Mac with SIP disabled. I'm not, so I just live with a Thunderbolt 27" Display and call it a day.